# Using Regex To find total occurrence of &T

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to find total count of &T that occurs in the a file. This txt file is read and I save this file in list

```
  Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
            wholeEBList.Add(sReader.ReadToEnd)
  Loop
```

How can I use Regex, can someone help me with code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am planning to use VB.Net.                                                              
The txt file looks like this :                                                        
{SYSTEM ENTITY TY_403B2( )                                                     }
&T REGPVNIM                                                                     
&N TY_403B2                                                                     
NODETYP  = HPM         
PNTFORM  = COMPONNT    
PTDESC   ="FA-403B BED HI SELECT   "
EUDESC   ="DEG F   "
KEYWORD  ="FA-403B "
ASSOCDSP ="        "
$CDETAIL ="        "

Comment: Private Sub FindTotalTags()
        Dim i As Integer

        Dim value As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pub_strSelectedPath & "\" & "Total.EB")
        Dim Pattern As String = "\&T\s"
        Debug.WriteLine(value)

        Debug.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(value, Pattern).Count)
        For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(value, Pattern)
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.",
                              m.Value, m.Index)
            i = i + 1
            Debug.WriteLine(i)
        Next


    End Sub

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew - Thanks.

Comment: Private Function FindTotalTags(path As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

   Dim value As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)
   Dim Pattern As String = "\&T\s"
   Debug.WriteLine(value)

  Return Regex.Matches(value, Pattern).Count()

Comment: I am not sure why this question is closed by Wiktor Stribiżew? This question is not same as one listed "how to find the number of occurrences of a substring within a string vb.net ".